# How to compile jxrlib on windows

Tags: windows, makefile, jpeg-xr

I am looking for a library for working with JPEG-XR images and imagemagick refers me to [`jxrlib`](https://jxrlib.codeplex.com/) provided by Microsoft.

There are no pre-built binaries. The source code comes with a make file, but when I try to build it using `GnuMake`, I run into errors saying that a `.o` file was not found.

```
cc -I. -Icommon/include -Iimage/sys -D__ANSI__ -DDISABLE_PERF_MEASUREMENT -w -O
-Ijxrgluelib -c jxrgluelib/JXRGlue.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -I. -Icommon/include -Iimage/sys -D__ANSI_
_ -DDISABLE_PERF_MEASUREMENT -w -O -Ijxrgluelib -c jxrgluelib/JXRGlue.c, ...) fa
iled.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [JXRGlue.o] Error 2
```

How do I compile this on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have Visual Studio installed, just open the included solution files and build. That has always worked for me. I can't say anything regarding other toolchains under Windows, but I know that it also builds successfully with make and gcc under Ubuntu.

If you can't get it to compile I can share binaries if that helps you.

Comment: Oh, I see the `.sln` files now. I'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio project files have been added to jxrlib project. See [Add vc14 project and solution files](https://jxrlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/e922fa50cdf9a58f40cad07553bcaa2883d3c5bf) commit in the official repository at https://jxrlib.codeplex.com

Alternatively, use CMake configuration proposed here in [Patch for warnigns + CMake for building](http://jxrlib.codeplex.com/workitem/13).